# How can I use Scala's MurmurHash implementation: scala.util.MurmurHash3?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9, murmurhash

I'm writing a BloomFilter and wanted to use Scala's default MurmurHash3 implementation: scala.util.MurmurHash3. My compile is failing however with the following compile error:

```
[error] /mnt/hgfs/dr/sandbox/dr-commons/src/main/scala/dr/commons/collection/BloomFilter.scala:214: MurmurHash3 is not a member of scala.util
[error]   import scala.util.{MurmurHash3 => MH}
```

I'm using Scala 2.9.1 and sbt 0.11.2.

Is the MurmurHash3 class not in the 2.9.1 library by default? I assume it is since it's used a lot in the library. The class isn't package private as far as I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called just [scala.util.MurmurHash](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.MurmurHash) without the 3. But it's indeed the Murmurhash 3 algorithm (see [the comments in the source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/util/MurmurHash.scala#L1))

**EDIT** I've just seen that Rex Kerr is the author of scala.util.MurmurHash. I would advise you not to accept this answer (assuming it's the correct one); since [Rex Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr) is on StackOverflow he may chime in and give you a much better one...

Comment: Thanks. What's the scala.util.MurmurHash3 class, then?

Comment: it seems to be the new version in  [scala 2.10](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.util.MurmurHash3)

Answer (score 4):

I am using scala 2.11 and spark apache 1.6.2 . Its working fine. With these versions I am not getting any error

```
import scala.util.hashing.{ MurmurHash3 => MH3 }
    val data="I am SANTHOSH"
    val sample = MH3.stringHash(data, MH3.stringSeed)
    println(":Hash Value: "+sample)
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Actually I missed to add the version I use. I used the scala 2.11.8 and apache 1.6.2

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

`import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3`